# Route between two networks on Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, routing

I am trying to route between two networks, both connected to my computer.
Current situation:

card #1:
IP: 172.18.37.64
Gateway: 172.18.36.1

card #2:
IP: 192.168.2.187
Gateway: 192.168.2.1

System is Windows XP SP3

Connected to card #1 is the network of my office, card #2 connects me to a small ADSL router.
My aim is to route all requests to the office network (all IPs in 172.0.0.0) over card #1 and all other traffic (internet) over card #2 to the ADSL router. Both networks provide DHCP and DNS.

Which rules do I have to add for this to work? I already tried it in my own, but my understanding of this is way too low.

Thank you in advance,

BliZZarD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

route add 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0 192.168.2.1 -p should route all traffic to the adsl router

route add 172.18.37.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.18.37.64 -p should then route all traffic destined for your work

You could also just specify an address manually on the work connection without a gateway, which will make all internet traffic go out of the other interface.

Comment: Thank you, but I think the range for the office-network is wrong, as it is the entire 172.xxx.yyy.zzz range AND why did yout put 172.18.37.64 as gateway? I think it should be 172.18.36.1, or am I wrong? So it should be: route add 172.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 172.18.36.1 -p

Please correct my if I am wrong :)

Comment: I think you need to modify that a little. Only the 172.16.0.0/12 subnet is meant for private networks. In other words, your above routing would cut off from a fair portion of Internet addresses. Use
route add 172.16.0.0 mask 255.240.0.0 gw 172.18.36.1

Comment: Because you are using the nic interface as the gateway.